How to troubleshoot why custom Finder search keeps breaking?
I use macOS 12.7.6. I have a custom Finder search (a .savedSearch) that searches a folder for files matching two criteria, Kind is Music (All) and Composer is not Example.
I set this up on an older version of macOS, and it worked for several years straight. Ever since upgrading to macOS 12 in 2022 though, it breaks literally daily. When it breaks, the search shows 0 results. Spotlight and Finder can find the actual files that should be shown, but only when searching system wide instead of in a specific folder. I have found two temporary solutions: reindexing the folder by disabling it in Spotlight and enabling it again, or running mdimport my/folder/here, but after a few hours or sometimes days, without fail, it breaks again and shows 0 results.
I have tried reinstalling macOS and deleting all Spotlight data I can find, but it made no differences. How do I troubleshoot this issue? Are there any relevant logs I could read?
EDIT: Creating a new .savedSearch does not solve the issue. The search also breaks even when I make it so narrow that it only shows 1 file. The same issue occurs also when creating a new folder and moving the contents over, and also on a mirrored version of my installation that has been upgraded to macOS Sonoma.

You may be triggering a bug, in which case it would be pointless to try to troubleshoot this. Can you update to a newer version of macOS?

@LincD. That's likely, but unfortunately I can't upgrade past macOS 12.

Delete the old saved search and recreate it after the reindexing has finished.

Let's proceed on the theory that Spotlight is choking on something in that particular folder. Make a copy of the folder and see whether you can reproduce the problem by searching it. If you can, remove about half the contents, reindex, and try again. Continuing in this way you may be able to isolate one or a few files as the culprits. That may be the best you can do.
